# Memory limits on Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have recently bought an [Arduino Uno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino#ArduinoUno), and now I am experimenting a bit with it. I have a couple of 18B20 sensors and an ENC28J60 network module connected to it, then I am making a sketch to allow me to connect to it from a browser and read out the temperatures either as a simple web page or as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). The code that makes the web pages looks like this:

```
client.print("Inne: ");
client.print(tempin);
client.println("<br />");
client.print("Ute: ");
client.print(tempout);
client.print("<br /><br />");
client.println(millis()/1000);
//    client.print("<a href=\"/json\">j</a>");
```

The strange thing is: if I uncomment the last line, the sketch compiles fine, uploads fine, but I cannot get to connect to the board. The same thing happens if I add on some more characters in some of the other printouts. Thus, it looks to me as if I'm running into some kind of memory limit (the total size of the sketch is about 15 KB, and there are some other strings used elsewhere in the code - and yes I know, I will rewrite it to use an array to store the temporaries, I've just stolen some code from an example).

Is there any limit on how much memory I can use to store strings in an Arduino and are there any way to get around that? (using [GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) v 1.0.1 on a [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) PC with GCC-AVR 4.3.5 and [AVR Libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) 1.6.8).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The RAM is rather small, as the UNO's 328 is only 2K. You may just be running out of RAM. I learned that when it runs out, it just kind of sits there.

I suggest reading the [readme](https://github.com/mpflaga/Arduino-MemoryFree) from this library to get the FreeRAM. It mentions how the ".print" can consume both RAM and ROM.

I always now use (for Arduino IDE 1.0.+)

```
Serial.print(F("HELLO"));
```

versus

```
Serial.print("HELLO");
```

as it saves RAM, and this should be true for lcd.print. Where I always put a

```
Serial.println(freeMemory(), DEC);  // print how much RAM is available.
```

in the beginning of the code, and pay attention. Noting that there needs to be room to run the actual code and re-curse into its subroutines.

For IDE's prior to 1.0.0 the library provides getPSTR()).

IDE 1.0.3 now starts to display the expected usage of RAM at the end of the compile. However, I find it is often short, as it is only an estimate.

---

I also recommend that you look at [Webduino](https://github.com/sirleech/Webduino) as it has a library that supports JSON. Its examples are very quick to get going. However it does not directly support the ENC28J60.

Comment: "just kind of sist there" yeah, exactly. Thanks! I'll check youyr advices

Comment: The "F" trick is brilliant and has fixed many strange errors with serial printing.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to get free available RAM

```
int getFreeRam()
{
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval; 
  int v;

  v = (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval);

  Serial.print("Free RAM = ");
  Serial.println(v, DEC);

  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the memory usage with a small lib called [memoryFree](https://github.com/maniacbug/MemoryFree).

When there is ram left, you might be pushing the serial buffer limit instead of the ram limit. If so, you can increase `SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE` in `HardwareSerial.cpp`

(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino` on a windows machine)

Be carefull though, ram and serial buffer are both stored on the SRAM. Increasing the serial buffer will result in less available memory for your variables.

For playing with JSON on the arduino there is a really nice lib, called [aJson](https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson).

Comment: this guy knows more about the [hardware serial buffer](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/arduino-serial-buffer-size)

Answer (score 0):

add this function and call it in setup and every now and then in your loop to make sure RAM is not being used up.

```
// Private function: from http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory  
int freeRam () {
  extern int __heap_start, *__brkval; 
  int v; 
  return (int) &v - (__brkval == 0 ? (int) &__heap_start : (int) __brkval); 
}
```

You need to call it for example inside a print:
Serial.println(freeRam());